# How to use MultiFieldQueryParser from Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, information-retrieval

I am using `Version.Lucene_29`. Using the normal string query method i could do the following:

```
Directory directory = new FSDirectory(...);
//Start Lucene retrieval.
IndexSearcher iSearch = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);
Analyzer analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, "content", analyzer);
String str = 'filename:testfile.txt AND filetext:"Singapore food"'
Query query = parser.parse(str);
ScoreDoc[] hits = iSearch.search(query, 1000).scoreDocs;
```

How do i fire a query using MultiFieldQueryParser in Lucene similar to the string query method?

```
MultiFieldQueryParser multiParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
    Version.LUCENE_29, new String[] {"content", "ne"}, analyzer);
str = ???
Query = ????
ScoreDoc[] hits = iSearch.search(query, 1000).scoreDocs;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MultiFieldQueryParser allows you to search for a "WORD" in more then one Fileds with same Analyzer.

e.g.

```
 Query query = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse("development",
        new String[]{"title", "subject"},
        new SimpleAnalyzer());
```

it will look for word development in Field : "title" and Field : "subject"

Comment: If there is a chance to have a keyword containing more than one word, eg. "software development", you will also need to set `MultiFieldQueryParser.setDefaultOperator(Operator.AND)`, otherwise it will find all the results containing "software" **OR** "development".

Comment: You can probably use a PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper and lift the restriction "with same Analyzer".

Answer (score 1):

`MultiFieldQueryParser` is-a `QueryParser`, `MultiFieldQueryParser` creates the two Queries into a `BooleanClause` in this case. So it also supports *filename:testfile.txt AND filetext:"Singapore food"*.